# Replacing multiplication operator in existing keras (tensorflow) model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I am currently using an existing Keras implementation of a certain model and I would like to study the effects of different multiplication implementations on its computational speed and accuracy.

Is there a simple way to replace the Keras (TensorFlow) multiplication that is used in its Dense and Conv (and other pre-existing) layers with a custom one?

The idea is also to see the difference between training with normal multiplication + testing with custom multiplication and doing both with the custom multiplication.

So I'm looking for a solution that's something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__mul__ = custom_mult
```

and will replace all multiplication operations in Keras's default layers with my own implementation.